# Play + Slick: How to do partial model updates?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I am using Play 2.2.x with Slick 2.0 (with MYSQL backend) to write a REST API. I have a `User` model with bunch of fields like `age`, `name`, `gender` etc. I want to create a route `PATCH /users/:id` which takes in partial user object (i.e. a subset of the fields of a full user model) in the body and updates the user's info. I am confused how I can achieve this:

1. How do I use `PATCH` verb in Play 2.2.x?
2. What is a generic way to parse the partial user object into an update query to execute in Slick 2.0?I am expecting to execute a single SQL statement e.g. `update users set age=?, dob=? where id=?`

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I haven't used Slick, so am just going by their documentation about [Plain SQL Queries](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/sql.html#query-statements) for this.*

To answer your first question:

`PATCH` is just-another HTTP verb in your `routes` file, so for your example:

```
PATCH       /users/:id          controllers.UserController.patchById(id)
```

Your `UserController` could then be something like this:

```
val possibleUserFields = Seq("firstName", "middleName", "lastName", "age")

def patchById(id:String) = Action(parse.json) { request =>

  def addClause(fieldName:String) = {
    (request.body \ fieldName).asOpt[String].map { fieldValue =>
      s"$fieldName=$fieldValue"
    }
  }

  val clauses = possibleUserFields.flatMap ( addClause )

  val updateStatement = "update users set " + clauses.mkString(",") + s" where id = $id"

  // TODO: Actually make the Slick call, possibly using the 'sqlu' interpolator (see docs)
  Ok(s"$updateStatement")
}
```

What this does:

- Defines the list of JSON field names that might be present in the `PATCH` JSON
- Defines an Action that will parse the incoming body as JSON
- Iterates over all of the possible field names, testing whether they exist in the incoming JSON
- If so, adds a clause of the form `fieldname=<newValue>` to a list
- Builds an SQL update statement, comma-separating each of these clauses as required

I don't know if this is generic enough for you, there's probably a way to get the field names (i.e. the Slick column names) out of Slick, but like I said, I'm not even a Slick user, let alone an expert :-)

Comment: How safe is this from SQL injections?

Comment: Not completely, it is recommended to use lifted embedding in slick (which is safe for SQL injections according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaquery/7HHTH2t-ULw/8KGZnS2kywAJ).
For updating, see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html#updating. This part of the doc assumes that you have a schema, see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/gettingstarted.html#schema

Comment: I'd actually say "_not safe at all_" - I deliberately tried to avoid putting any Slick API calls in my example above for that reason. Looking over the Slick docs again now, it should be possible to use the `update` method from `StaticQuery` (or just `Q.u`) to at least get a parameterized query instead of a dumb string-concatenated query.

Comment: How can use Q.u when the number of parameters is variable in this case?